# Retrieve specific user data from firebase in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

the collection name is the specific user id i want to retrieve data for the specific user. how can i do that. this is the screen shot of my database [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNEMC.png)
i tried this code but it return only the 1st collection because of the array

```
StreamBuilder(
       stream: Firestore.instance.collection("/userdata").snapshots(),
       builder: (context, snapshot) {
     gnickname = snapshot.data.documents[0]["Nickname"];
     gphotourl = snapshot.data.documents[0]["photoURL"];})
```

Comment: You are trying to get all the records in the `userdata` collection right, but you are only getting the first one?

Comment: no i want to get a specific data with the help of uid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a specific record based on the uid use, in your case, the following code:

`var userData = Firestore.instance.collection("/userdata").document("uid").get();`

`userData` is a `DocumentSnapshot` so use `userData.data`  object to get the key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You  can do it like that for first collection

```
   StreamBuilder(
           stream: Firestore.instance.collection("/userdata").snapshots(),
           builder: (context, snapshot) {
         gnickname = snapshot.data.documents.first["Nickname"];
         gphotourl = snapshot.data.documents.first["photoURL"];})
```

Answer (score 0):

To get specific user you can try:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('your_collection').document('your_id').snapshots()
```