# How to get a specific user data with the help of uid?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My question is based on this one:
[Retrieve specific user data from firebase in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61117689/retrieve-specific-user-data-from-firebase-in-flutter).
There is answer how to get user data using user id, but I don't know how to get some specific user data, e.g. how to get name or age.

Summary:

1. Every user has unique id and name, age, address.
2. I have user id and I want to get another user data, e.g. I want to get name of that user. How?

Comment: Can you provide more information. Where is this User class coming from? Did you create it or is it from [`firebase_auth`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User-class.html), etc?

Comment: In this question is user just an example, I'd like to know how to do it in any class I create. 
Another example is survey. I've got survey id and survey is created by registered user. Registered user must enter survey title, description and duration (that will be saved in database). Unregistered user must enter survey id to take a survey. After he entered id, I want to open view where he can see survey title and duration. And I don't know how to access to survey duration or title to show only that informations.

Comment: It seems like you're asking how to read data from Firebase? If so there's a great [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/7426050-firebase-tutorial-for-flutter-getting-started) available as well as dozens of others and even some youtube videos. If that's not what's being asked, can you clarify the question and include the code you've attempted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a collection named users,this collection will have many documents by the name of userIds, each document will have Map-like structure e.g. `"name":string,` 'age":int, 'address':string . Since you have the id from firebase login , just `DocumentSnapshot document = await Firestore.instance.collection("/userdata").document("uid").get();`

From there you could construct your user class or use `document['name']` immediately

Comment: The await expression can only be used in an async function. How to solve that? 

If I make function like this, how to call it to get what I want?
getOneFormData(String uid) async{
    return await Firestore.instance.collection("/userdata").document("uid").get();
  }

Comment: You could use a FutureBuilder with a future : yourAsyncFunction. Just like you wrap a Contaner around your widgets!

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is that you would like to make something like SELECT x,y,z i have to say you cannot..

You have to first retreive the document by its uniqueId then you can read specifica data

Comment: Could you please give me code example how to read specific data after I retrieve the document?