# Flutter: How to fetch a particular record from firebase

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is the screenshot of my database.

I want to fetch the record for a particular username. (For eg: where user=nam@gmail.com) Can anyone suggest to me how to fetch this in flutter?

[image]

It would be a great help, Thank you.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If not, have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries and/or https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#querying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the data, you can create a function like:

```dart
Future getData(String username) async {
    List dataList = [];
    try {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userdata').where('user', isEqualTo: username).get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
              itemList.add(doc.data());
            }),
          });
      return itemList;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

When you'll call this function, you will have to pass the `username` and it would return a list of data items.

This list can then be used to show data in the UI as:

```dart
 child: Text(
            title: Text(subjectList[index]['user']),
           ),
```

Comment: Please refer the FlutterFire - Cloud Firestore usage documentation here: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage

Answer (score 1):

you can try this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61117689/retrieve-specific-user-data-from-firebase-in-flutter) it helped me, but if you have migrated to null safety just make sure that you change the code accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following query to get your result.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('your-collection-name')
  .where('user', arrayContains: 'nam@gmail.com')
  .get();
```

Comment: Future<QuerySnapshot> user = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('userdata')
                            .where('user', arrayContains: email)
                            .get(); This helps, but also can you tell me how to print my data using user?

Comment: If you want to get/ print all the `user` key values from the firebase collection. You can simple use the same query without the condition statement `arrayContains: email`.

`Future<QuerySnapshot> user = FirebaseFirestore.instance .collection('userdata') .where('user').get();`

Comment: How to get a particular key-value pair? Suppose, I want to get the weight of the user, how to do that?

Comment: Hi @MahishaPatel, In Firebase we store the values in map type. So, If you want to get the weight of a user, you should pass the key (weight) into the where method. Like 
`FirebaseFirestore.instance .collection('userdata') .where('weight').get();`

Comment: When I print user, I just get this : ```Instance of 'Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>'```

Comment: The query returns the entire instance of those user records have weight. If you want to print the weight for the returned collection alone, you can get it in the following way.
```snapshot.data!.docs.forEach((doc) => print(doc.get('weight')));```

Answer (score 0):

For android solution follow this:

```
 FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("users").whereArrayContains("user","nam@gmail.com").get();
```